# Anomaly in the Graph of a Function.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, trigonometry, graphing-functions, absolute-value

Let $f(x) = \sqrt{1+ \cos 2x}$ , $x \in(\frac{\pi}{2},\pi]$ , where $\cos$ is negative.

On solving , $f(x)$ comes out to be $\sqrt{\cos²x}$. Now its result can be $+/- \cos x$ , $\cos x$ being $-ve$ and $-\cos x$ being $+ve$ . In both the cases the original function remains valid . But on graphing it online the plotted graph only shows the positive value of $\cos x $

[image]
(Ignore the other functions )
Why is it happening ?

Comment: Please use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: maybe [related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1549420/is-sqrt-cos2x-cos-x)

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! $\sqrt{\cos^2x}=|\cos x|$, not $\cos x$.

Comment: Because that is what the function looks like. When $\cos(x) \geq 0$ then the function is just $\cos(x)$ and when $\cos(x)<0$ then the function is $-\cos(x)$. In both cases the function is just the absolute value of $\cos(x)$.

Comment: If $x>0$ then _by definition_ $\sqrt x$ is the _positive_ square root.